# How to create before and after scores in two different columns based on date?

Tags: r

I have two tables first table has stress score recorded at various time points and second table has date of treatment. I want to get the stress scores before and after treatment for each participant who has received the treatment. Also I want a column that gives information on when was the stress score recorded before and after treatment. I do not understand from where do I begin,and what should my code look like.

```
score.dt = data.table(
  participant.index = c(1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 4, 13, 21, 21, 25, 37, 40, 41, 41, 41, 43, 43, 43, 44),
  repeat.instance = c(2, 3, 6, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1),
  date.recorded = c(
    '2017-07-13',
    '2017-06-26',
    '2018-09-17',
    '2016-04-14',
    '2014-03-24',
    '2016-05-30',
    '2018-06-20',
    '2014-08-03',
    '2015-07-06',
    '2014-12-17',
    '2014-09-05',
    '2013-06-10',
    '2015-10-04',
    '2016-11-04',
    '2016-04-18',
    '2014-02-13',
    '2013-05-24',
    '2014-09-10',
    '2014-11-25'
  ),
  subscale = c(
    "stress",
    "stress",
    "stress",
    "stress",
    "stress",
    "stress",
    "stress",
    "stress",
    "stress",
    "stress",
    "stress",
    "stress",
    "stress",
    "stress",
    "stress",
    "stress",
    "stress",
    "stress",
    "stress"
  ),
  score = c(18, 10, 18, 36, 16, 30, 28, 10, 12, 40, 16, 12, 10, 14, 6, 32, 42, 26, 18)
)

date.treatment.dt = data.table (
  participant.index = c(1, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 11, 12, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26),
  date.treatment = c(
    '2018 - 06 - 27',
    '2001 - 07 - 16',
    '2009 - 12 - 09',
    '2009 - 05 - 20',
    '2009 - 07 - 22',
     '2008-07 - 02',
    '2009 - 11 - 25',
    '2009 - 09 - 16',
    '1991 - 07 - 30',
    '2016 - 05 - 25',
    '2012 - 07 - 25',
    '2007 - 03 - 19',
    '2012 - 01 - 25',
    '2011 - 09 - 21',
    '2000 - 03 - 06',
    '2001 - 09 - 25',
    '1999 - 12 - 20',
    '1997 -07 - 28',
    '2002 - 03 - 12',
    '2008 - 01 - 23'
  ))
```

Desired output columns: is something like this

```
score.date.dt = c("candidate.index.x", "repeat.instance", "subscale", "score", "date.treatment", "date.recorded", "score.before.treatment", "score.after.treatment", "months.before.treatment", "months.after.treatment")
```

Here the columns months.before.treatment indicates how many months before treatment the stress score was measured and month.after.treatment indicates how many months after treatment the stress score was measured.

Comment: In your output you only want to see participants that had treatment (i.e. are in the first table) AND had a stress score (i.e. are in the second table) right?

Comment: Thanks Dan. Yes you got me right. My biggest concern is getting the before and after score.

Answer (score 1):

In your example set, you only have four individuals with stress scores that have any rows in the treatment table (participants 1,4,21,and 25). Only one of these, participant 1, has both a pre-treatment stress measures and post-treatment stress measure...

Here is one way to produce the information you need:

```
inner_join(score.dt,date.treatment.dt, by="participant.index") %>% 
  group_by(participant.index, date.treatment) %>% 
  summarize(pre_treatment = min(date.recorded[date.recorded<=date.treatment]),
            post_treatment = max(date.recorded[date.recorded>=date.treatment])) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -(participant.index:date.treatment), names_to = "period", values_to = "date.recorded") %>% 
  left_join(score.dt, by=c("participant.index", "date.recorded" )) %>% 
  mutate(period=str_extract(period,".*(?=_)"),
         months =  abs(as.numeric(date.treatment-date.recorded))/(365.25/12)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = participant.index:date.treatment, names_from = period, values_from=c(date.recorded, subscale, months,score))
```

Output:

```
  participant.index date.treatment date.recorded_pre date.recorded_post subscale_pre subscale_post months_pre months_post score_pre score_post
              <dbl> <date>         <date>            <date>             <chr>        <chr>              <dbl>       <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>
1                 1 2018-06-27     2017-06-26        2018-09-17         stress       stress              12.0        2.69        10         18
2                 4 2001-07-16     NA                2016-05-30         NA           stress             Inf        178.          NA         30
3                21 2000-03-06     NA                2015-07-06         NA           stress             Inf        184.          NA         12
4                25 2002-03-12     NA                2014-12-17         NA           stress             Inf        153.          NA         40
```

Note: you will have to fix the date inputs to the two source files, like this:

```
# first correct, your date.treatment column, and convert to date
date.treatment.dt[, date.treatment := as.Date(str_replace_all(date.treatment," ",""), "%Y-%m-%d")]

# second, similarly fix the date column in your stress score table
score.dt[,date.recorded := as.Date(date.recorded,"%Y-%m-%d")]
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there are a few parts to what you're asking. First, you need to merge the two tables together. Here I use `dplyr::inner_join()` which automatically detects that the `candidate.index` is the only column in common and merges on that while discarding records found in only one of the tables. Second, we convert to a date format for both dates to enable the calculation of elapsed months.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

score.dt <- structure(list(participant.index = c(1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 4, 13, 21, 21, 25, 37, 40, 41, 41, 41, 43, 43, 43, 44), repeat.instance = c(2, 3, 6, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1), date.recorded = c("2017-07-13", "2017-06-26", "2018-09-17", "2016-04-14", "2014-03-24", "2016-05-30", "2018-06-20", "2014-08-03", "2015-07-06", "2014-12-17", "2014-09-05", "2013-06-10", "2015-10-04", "2016-11-04", "2016-04-18", "2014-02-13", "2013-05-24", "2014-09-10", "2014-11-25"), subscale = c("stress", "stress", "stress", "stress", "stress", "stress", "stress", "stress", "stress", "stress", "stress", "stress", "stress", "stress", "stress", "stress", "stress", "stress", "stress"), score = c(18, 10, 18, 36, 16, 30, 28, 10, 12, 40, 16, 12, 10, 14, 6, 32, 42, 26, 18)), row.names = c(NA, -19L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
  

date.treatment.dt <- structure(list(participant.index = c(1, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 11, 12, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26), date.treatment = c("2018 - 06 - 27", "2001 - 07 - 16", "2009 - 12 - 09", "2009 - 05 - 20", "2009 - 07 - 22", "2008-07 - 02", "2009 - 11 - 25", "2009 - 09 - 16", "1991 - 07 - 30", "2016 - 05 - 25", "2012 - 07 - 25", "2007 - 03 - 19", "2012 - 01 - 25", "2011 - 09 - 21", "2000 - 03 - 06", "2001 - 09 - 25", "1999 - 12 - 20", "1997 -07 - 28", "2002 - 03 - 12", "2008 - 01 - 23")), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
  
inner_join(date.treatment.dt, score.dt) %>% 
  mutate(across(contains("date"), as_date)) %>% 
  mutate(months.after = interval(date.treatment, date.recorded) %/% months(1)) %>% 
  mutate(months.before = 0 - months.after)
#> Joining, by = "participant.index"
#>    participant.index date.treatment repeat.instance date.recorded subscale
#> 1:                 1     2018-06-27               2    2017-07-13   stress
#> 2:                 1     2018-06-27               3    2017-06-26   stress
#> 3:                 1     2018-06-27               6    2018-09-17   stress
#> 4:                 4     2001-07-16               1    2014-03-24   stress
#> 5:                 4     2001-07-16               2    2016-05-30   stress
#> 6:                21     2000-03-06               1    2014-08-03   stress
#> 7:                21     2000-03-06               2    2015-07-06   stress
#> 8:                25     2002-03-12               1    2014-12-17   stress
#>    score months.after months.before
#> 1:    18          -11            11
#> 2:    10          -12            12
#> 3:    18            2            -2
#> 4:    16          152          -152
#> 5:    30          178          -178
#> 6:    10          172          -172
#> 7:    12          184          -184
#> 8:    40          153          -153
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>